# JReport - Truncating String on Table Width

Tags: java, report, reporting

Is it possible to truncate a string based on the width of a table rather than setting a character limit in JReport?

Currently, a character limit is being used to truncate the strings but this is not ideal as different characters vary in length and so the width at which the strings are being truncated are not consistent. For example:

[image: Current situation]

Ideally, I'd like to truncate it based on a set width instead so that I get something like this:

[image: Ideal situation]

Thanks!

Comment: I have never found a way to do that with JReport. The only way I can do that is with a server side script. I would recommand you the same